# Positioning Cardviews below eachother not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to position a few Cardviews below eachother in a RelativeLayout, but it isn't working out so far. The cardviews are all on top of eachother, but layout_below is set for all of them. It's pretty strange, because it did work in the past if I recall correctly.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com"
xmlns:android.support.v7.cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="something.something.fragments.RosterFragment"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:id="@+id/rosterContainer0">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/cardViewMonday"
            android:longClickable="true"
            style="@style/InformationCard">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/TitleLightBackground"
                android:text="Maandag"
                android:id="@+id/dateMonday" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rosterListViewMonday"
                android:background="@color/white">
            </ListView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/cardViewTuesday"
            android:longClickable="true"
            style="@style/InformationCard"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardViewMonday">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/TitleLightBackground"
                android:text="Dinsdag"
                android:id="@+id/dateTuesday" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rosterListViewTuesday"
                android:background="@color/white">
            </ListView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/cardViewWednesday"
            android:longClickable="true"
            style="@style/InformationCard"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardViewTuesday">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/TitleLightBackground"
                android:text="Maandag"
                android:id="@+id/dateWednesday" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rosterListViewWednesday"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dateWednesday"
                android:background="@color/white">
            </ListView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/cardViewThursday"
            android:longClickable="true"
            style="@style/InformationCard"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardViewWednesday">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/TitleLightBackground"
                android:text="Maandag"
                android:id="@+id/dateThursday" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rosterListViewThursday"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dateThursday"
                android:background="@color/white">
            </ListView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/cardViewFriday"
            android:longClickable="true"
            style="@style/InformationCard"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardViewThursday">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/TitleLightBackground"
                android:text="Maandag"
                android:id="@+id/dateFriday" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rosterListViewFriday"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dateFriday"
                android:background="@color/white">
            </ListView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch out when you copy - paste code.

All your cards have the attribute android:layout_alignParentTop="true"